# Unable to show hidden files on Mac

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

I just received a new MacBook, running OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, from my new employer and I am unable to force hidden files to show in Finder.  This is my fourth MacBook, and in the past I have always used `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` to show hidden files; however, on my new Mac, this is not showing the hidden files. I also tried `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` but still cannot see hidden files in Terminal or in Finder.  I restarted my computer, but that didn't solve my issue either.  Any ideas on how to show my Mac's hidden files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you run the `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` command, 
hold the 'option/alt' key, then right click on the Finder icon in the dock and click Relaunch.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true; killall Finder
```

This sets AppleShowAllFiles to true which tells Finder to show all file. Note the -bool part, that tells will make sure you are setting a Boolean to it instead of string, integer etc. Finally it restarts Finder.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: @Allan Edited with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since High Sierra, you can show hidden files in the Finder with the key command: <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Period</kbd>. This also toggles the show/hide status.

No need for Terminal commands or third-party utilities, or relaunching the Finder.

Comment: RE: "No need for Terminal commands or third-party utilities, or relaunching the Finder." -- While that statement has been true since **macOS Sierra** (10.12) it was however not true at the time when the question was asked, as at that time the current **Apple** operating system was **OS X El Capitan** (10.11) and did require what the accepted answer states, or the use of a _third-party utility_.

Comment: RE: "This also toggles the view." --  What? The view in **Finder**  typically refers to, as Icons, as List, as Columns, as Gallery and pressing **⌘⇧.**  does not change the view.

Comment: @user3439894 OK, poorly phrased: this toggles the view status of hidden files. Will add "since High Sierra", too.

Answer (score 0):

### Detailed

**You can make all hidden files visible with this command in the Finder.**

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles 1 && killall Finder
```

**However, I prefer not to display hidden system files via the terminal, but rather with a shortcut.**

```
CMD + SHIFT + .
```

**If you want, you can make a file (several files) visible or invisible again.** - *Even if you remove the "hidden" attribute with chflags, this has no effect if setfile has also stored an attribute*

```
chflags hidden /path/to/file (Hides the file from the Finder)

chflags nohidden /path/to/file (Does not hide the file from the Finder)
```

*If the file cannot be made visible again, it may have been hidden using setfile.* `SetFile`

```
setfile -a V /path/to/file (Hides the file from the Finder)

setfile -a v /path/to/file (Does not hide the file from the Finder)
```

(To use this command you need the developer tools) `xcode-select --install`

*Note: There are several types of "hidden" files: those that begin with a period and those that are hidden with chflags or the developer's command line utility Setfile.*

**You can see the hidden files that were hidden with `chflags` here**

```
 ls -lO /path/to/directory
```

Comment: There are two types of "hidden" files: Those starting with a dot, and those set to hidden with `chflags hidden`. Your answer applies partially to either but doesn't clearly differentiate.